# Getting a HTTP 404 CAS Server SingleLogoutService

Tags: cas

I am testing the SLO aka *Single Logout Service* for **HTTP Redirect** SAML 2.0 binding. I am able to SSO successfully but I need a HTTP Redirect endpoint on CAS to point to from my SAML-SP for SLO. The endpoint I am getting a 404 is http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO.

For SSO, the endpoint http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO is working fine.

My CAS version is `5.0.6`.

Here is a snippet from my Idp metadata xml with the endpoints for SLO and SSO :

```
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO"/>
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SLO"/>
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SLO"/>
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/SOAP/SLO"/>
<NameIDFormat>urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier</NameIDFormat
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat><SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SSO"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://cas-server:8080/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"/>
```

Please help me understand if HTTP Redirect is supported for SLO scenarios.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [5.0.x documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/Configuring-SAML2-Authentication.html), the following endpoints are supported:

```
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SLO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/Unsolicited/SSO
```

If you see the [5.1.x documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configuring-SAML2-Authentication.html), the endpoints are as follows:

```
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SLO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/Unsolicited/SSO
/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/SOAP/ECP
```

So at a minimum, you need to be on 5.1.x, or better yet, latest patch release of 5.3.x if you have to stay on Java 8.